# Задача на два движущихся объекта. Ошибка "ожидалось имя процедуры или функции"

Tags: pascal

Задача следующая: два объекта могут двигаться в любых направлениях (навстречу друг другу, в разные стороны или в одну сторону), каждый из них имеет свою скорость и ускорение. Нужно выяснить, встретятся ли они и если да, то через сколько времени. В одной строке выдается ошибка, не знаю, как исправить, укажите в чем проблема, пожалуйста.

```
var x1,x2,dx1,dx2,a1,a2,t,abs:real;
begin
  readln(x1,x2,dx1,dx2,a1,a2);
  t:=0;
  while (abs(x2-x1)>2) and (t<1000000) do begin ///Ожидалось имя процедуры или функции
    x1:=x1+dx1+a1;
    x2:=x2+dx2+a2;
    dx1:=dx1+a1;
    dx2:=dx2+a2;
    t:=t+1;
  end;
  writeln(t);
    if (x2-x1=2) then writeln ('встретятся')
    else write('рандеву не произошло');
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перекрыли определение функции `Abs`:

```pascal
var x1,x2,dx1,dx2,a1,a2,t,abs:real;
```

Ну и переменная `p` не определена.

Comment: Насчет p: поправил, это должна была быть t.
А вот что касается abs, то я не совсем понимаю, так как использую это впервые.

Comment: `Abs` — встроенная функция языка паскаль.  Если вы объявляете переменную с таким же названием, то вы больше не можете её использовать.  Уберите объявление переменной и сможете использовать функцию.